# Android Emulator - "Encryption unsuccessful"

Tags: android-emulator, android-studio-2.3

Almost every time I try to open the emulator is giving me this error after a long loading pause.

I have tried to fix it by reinstalling the SDK, but no luck.

Note: I must say that I am new to Android.

[image]

Comment: This is happening because your phone is still trying to use your internal sdcard, but it isn't accessible. You will need to trick your phone to use the external sdcard as if it was the internal.

Comment: How can I do this in Android Studio?

Comment: If you are using Xamarin Visual Studio the "Factory Reset" option also works

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Wiping data in Android Virtual Device Manager helped me in my case.

**Tools** -> **Android** -> **AVD Manager** -> **Actions** *(triangle down)* -> **Wipe Data**

[image: Android Virtual Device Manager]

There is also *Advanced settings* in virtual device's configuration (*the pencil*) where is a configuration of SD card and internal storage, but I didn't have to change it.

Comment: Thank you. It worked! However, it is still booting extremely slow.

Comment: @CristianaDumitru You're welcome, Android emulator is terribly slow - it's always better to use a real device. Check if you use x86 (or x86_64) version of an image in the emulator, it's faster than ARM version.

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2019 16.8.3 I had to follow similar steps but Tools > Android Device Manager > ... > Factory Reset

Answer (score 11):

Android Device Manager > Stop your device and right click > Factory Reset

Answer (score 2):

My problem was two-fold. It turned out that I only needed to apply one set of fixes to address both of them!

Laptop had the OP's error, with the added "Gboard stopped" message superimposed on top of it

Dev-rig's Android Emulator was just a black screen that never changed!

## How to fix

1. Go to Tools -> Android -> Android SDK Manager
2. Run all the pre-selected updates
3. Go to the Tools tab
4. Expand "Android SDK Tools" and select the latest available, or v26.x.
5. Expand "Android SDK Build Tools" and make sure you have the ability to actually build whatever you just selected in #4
6. Run those updates
7. ... and Bob's your uncle!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you've already figured it out at this point, but one thing that helped me was simply right-clicking it in the Android Device Manager, and then clicking on 'Start with Factory Default.'

[image]

it's grayed out in mine because I've already done it Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In recent Android Studio versions, you can achieve the same results with this

> **AVD Manager -> Select device -> Cooled Boot Now**

or this

> **AVD Manager -> Select device -> Edit -> Advanced -> Boot option: Cool Boot**